# Dell XPS - Installing Ubuntu on external drive - Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST)

Tags: 20.04, external-hdd, rst

**Hardware:**
I have a Dell XPS 7590

**OS**
Preinstalled with Windows 10. Looking to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an external USB.

**Goal:**
I would like to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto an external SSD drive plugged in via USB 3 for occasional use. I want to do this without changing from RAID to AHCI in the Bios.

**Problem:**
After booting into Ubuntu using a small thumb drive. I was expecting to go through the install wizard and select the other external large SSD drive as the permanent Ubuntu install. Unfortunately, the Dell XPS uses Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST). This prompts an error stopping the installation dead in its tracks.

If I understand the error correctly it only impacts my internal SSD drive which I don't want to touch. The XPS is a work machine which I have full admin rights to and access to the bios but I am inclined to keep it close to stock in the Bios and I don't want to make registry changes in Windows. Either way, why should I have to?

Does anyone know of a workaround or is this not even possible and I have to change RST.

Kind Regards
Rich

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Ubuntu RST documentation](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347)?

Comment: I would temporarily turn RST off, install & then turn it back on. Expect but do not know that install would work since USB neither RST nor AHCI. Have seem many add AHCI Windows drivers and have to turn RST back on to boot into Windows to turn it off with internal install of Ubuntu. With UEFI, you have to partition in advance to include ESP - efi system partition on external drive. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 My external SSD almost as fast as internal, but flash drive slow.

Comment: I like this approach Oldfred. What happens if I accidentally boot into windows with RST off does it just fail to boot or is there any chance of damaging the windows installation?

Comment: User535733 if your not a bot, I've skimmed the documentation as the installation process did provide a handy link to that page. In there I only saw guidance on how to remove RST with windows installed. If at all possible I am aiming to avoid that as it feels unessasary because I am using an external drive.